# Why this class does not return false|| true?

Tags: javascript

I have this class

```
Class.V = function(v) {
    if (v.BooleanValue == true) {
        v.Success();
    } else {
        v.Fail();
    }

    return Class;
}
```

And i have a button which will execute a function that will returns true or false to procede or not with the form.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return check()" Value="Check" />


function check() {
    Class.V({
        BooleanValue: true,
        Success: function() {
            return true;
        },
        Fail: function() {
            return false;
        }
    })
```

But it doest work. This work instead:

```
function check() {
    Class.V({
        o: true,
        Success: function() {
            results = true;
        },
        Fail: function() {
            results = false;
        }
        return results;
        //now works as expected
        })
```

Why this happen?

Comment: This is a bit tangential, but I recommend http://javascript.crockford.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your current code, you have to propagate the return values of your inner functions from your outer function:

```
Class.V = function(v)
{
    if (v.BooleanValue) {
        return v.Success();
    } else {
        return v.Fail();
    }

    return Class;
}
```

Comment: voted up cuz for such a good clear and direct description and example

Answer (score 0):

You need to further return the values that the `v.Success` and `v.Fail` functions return to `Class.V`:

```
if (v.BooleanValue) {
    return v.Success();
    // ^ return here
} else {
    return v.Fail();
    // ^ and here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to return the value of your methods:

```
Class.V = function(v)
{
if(v.BooleanValue==true)
{
   return v.Success();
}
else{
   return v.Fail();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` only affects the current function call, not the chain. In the case of your first block of code, `return true;` only returns from the anonymous callback. You have to pass it along. Something like this:

```
Class.V = function(v) {
    return v.BooleanValue ? v.Success() : return v.Fail();
}

function check() {
    return Class.V({
      BooleanValue: true,
      Success:function() {
          return true;
      },
      Fail:function() {
          return false;
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: do you need the `return` on `return v.Fail();` if you're using it in a tertiary like that?

Comment: Nope, the `return` applies to the whole `?:` piece.